# Rails 4 - 2 word model names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, pundit, states

I'm using rails 4 with pundit and with statesman.

In each case, my pundit policy and my statesman model files don't work where the model name attached to them has two words.

For example, I have a model called organisation_request.rb

I have setup a pundit OrganisationRequestPolicy (in the same way I have set up every other pundit policy that applies to a model with a single word model name) and a state_tranistions file OrganisationRequestTransition (organisation_request_transition).

The pundit/statesman files don't work. The only difference I can see is that the model name has two words.

Is there a special convention for working with two word model names with these gems?

Comment: In which folders did you put the files?

Comment: the pundit policy is in my policies folder. the statesman files are in the models folder

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?